# I am looking to present the greatest predictor of performance given the following R output for multiple linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I used Linear regression analysis with a sample and recieved the table below. How do I interpret the results?

The underlying problem is finding the greatest contributor to $SMTQ$.

- $SMTQ$ - Sports Mental Toughness Questionaire
- $Confa$ - Confidence
- $Consa$ - Constancy
- $Conta$ - Control

How do I understand the result sin the table? Is there any reason to calculate the standardized regression coefficients rather than the unstandardised ones listed in table? Should I present both values for a valid interpretation?

[image: R output]

Comment: Why do you think hierarchical is preferable, or even possible here?

Comment: We have an r2 value for total smtq rather than individual measures. When looking for the greatest predictor this would have been helpful.

Comment: please indicate full form of your abrevitions and sime_thing about objectives of your study and the sample.

Comment: Depending on what is the real question (we don't know it yet) I would use semipartial $R^2$ and use the bootstrap to get a 0.95 compatibility interval for the rank of predictor importance on this metric.  For an example see Section 5.4 of [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf).  Bootstrapping ranks fully exposes the difficulty of the ranking task and often will prevent one from declaring a clear winner.

Comment: See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4554/919 for the close reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one statistically significant covariate, which is 'smtq$confa' with p-value 4.65e-13. Other coefficients are not statistically significant even at 10% level. Standardization would not affect the p-values. Hierarchical or multiple linear regression would not give you different results in your setup, given the magnitude of the p-values for different coefficients.

So, the covariate 'smtq$confa' is the best predictor in your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input. What values are best to present when discussing the findings?

Comment: It depends on the field of your study. In Statistics related works, usually the detailed output of the computation, which you have presented in the question, is presented first. Then, the significant predictors are stated based on the p-values. Finally, the implications are discussed. In other fields, where the statistical methodology is used only to identify the significant variables, the implications are more stressed upon, and the variables which are not statistically significant are ignored from the discussion or presentation.

Comment: pvalues of such t-test for the covariates would not be affected by standardization. An an example, [compare the pvalues obtained in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/93400/344944).

Comment: @joy statistical "significance" is an arbitrary concept that should not play a role here.

Comment: @FrankHarrell it is not clear to me why would you call statistical significance an arbitrary concept, although I agree that it depends on the nominal level, which is (somewhat arbitrarily) set to 5%, 1%, etc. In this particular case, from the p-values, it is seen that only one p-value is not only small but effectively 0, while others are relatively large. So, it will be 'statistically significant' according to its definition for almost any arbitrarily set nominal level.

Comment: Because it is clearly not helpful in general to get excited about a predictor with p=0.049 while ignoring a predictor with p=0.051 (I realize things are more extreme for the current dataset).  Statistical significance should play no role here.  Instead, quantify the predictive value of **all** or the pre-specified predictors.

Comment: I agree with your statement about not getting "excited about a predictor with p=0.049 while ignoring a predictor with p=0.051". On the other hand, it is perhaps hard for things to get more extreme than they are in the current dataset. Regarding your assertion that statistical significance should play no role, particularly in view of the current set of p-values, I would say that your stand is in a philosophical disagreement with perhaps the dominant view in the statistical community, which can be clearly seen to influence the very format of the results presented in R for the current analysis.

Comment: Although everything you write is plausible, it's not necessarily correct. On the face of it -- with just the given information -- one cannot determine which might be a "best predictor," because these statistics tell us little about prediction.  For instance, it's possible the "most significant" variable contributes little to the prediction after the other variables are included, but those others don't look "significant" because they are highly correlated.  We also have no information about effect sizes -- and reporting standardized coefficients would actually help with that.